# Don't allow text entry in numericUpDown

Tags: c#, winforms, numericupdown

I have a WinForm in C# with an NumericUpDown Control on it. I want the Control to change its value only after clicking on its up or down arrow, and to block the manual text entries, is there a property of NumericUpDown to do this, or any other way to implement?

Comment: Have you considered that those who use your UI might expect to be able to type the number in. It's this sort of thing that gets us a bad name you know.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
numericUpDown.ReadOnly = true;
```

Comment: It disables textbox entry but the up/down buttons still change its value.

Comment: Oh, I see, sorry your answer is the easiest but he also should change th backgroundcolor because on readonly it´s ugly gray -.-

Comment: To correct the ugly gray backgroundcolor numericUpDown.Backcolor = Color.White; or set the backcolor to ActiveCaptionText from the UI.

Answer (score 2):

Please find below code which meets your requirement and might solve your issue:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Load += new EventHandler(Form1_Load);
        }

        void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            numericUpDown1.KeyDown+=new KeyEventHandler(numericUpDown1_KeyDown);
        }

        void numericUpDown1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            return;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may disable the CanFocus Property, so the user can´t focus the textarea but can click the up/down buttons.

```
numericUpDown1.CanFocus = false;
```

Comment: CanFocus property can not be set.